# Call React state methods from external function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I am building a React functional component that uses some state variables, and I am trying to modify some of these variables from an external function thats called on a button click event, but when I pass the reference to the state methods to this external function, all of them are **undefined**. What could be the cause? If I just put the exact same code within the functional component, it works perfectly as intended.

```
import React from "react";
import {CodeArea, Table, EmptyField, Button} from '../util/util.js'
import {Step, Load} from "./buttons.js" // The external function in question, Loadfunction 

Core(props){
    const registersInitial = new Array(32).fill(0);
    let buttonNamesInitial = ['LOAD','play', 'step-forward', 'run-to', 'step-back','pause','halt', 'rerun', 'add'];

    const [bigText, setText] = React.useState();
    const [registers, setRegisters] = React.useState(registersInitial);
    const [running, setRunning] = React.useState(false);
    const [programCounter, setProgramCounter] = React.useState(0);
    const [buttonNames, setButtonNames] = React.useState(buttonNamesInitial);
    const [lines, setLines] = React.useState([]);

    const getBigText = () => {
        return bigText;
    }
    const getRunning = () =>{
        return running;
    }
    const getButtonNames = () => {
        return buttonNames;
    }
    
    //... some code here thats irrelevant
    
    function getQuickbarContents(){
        let functions = [ //Backend will come here
            () => Load(setRunning, getRunning, setButtonNames, getButtonNames, setProgramCounter, setLines, getBigText), //Where Load gets called
            () => console.log("code running..."),
            () => console.log("stepping to next line..."),
            () => console.log("running to location..."),
            () => console.log("stepping..."),
            () => console.log("pausing..."),
            () => console.log("halting..."),
            () => console.log("running again..."),
            () => console.log("select widget to add...")
        ]
        let contents = [];
        let row = [];
        for (let i = 0; i<9; i++){
            row.push(<Button onClick ={functions[i]} className='quickbar' name={buttonNames[i]}/>);
            contents.push(row);
            row = [];
        }
        return contents
    }
    
    const divs = [];
    
    let buttons = getQuickbarContents();
    divs.push(<div key='left' className='left'><Table name='quickbar' rows='7' cols='1' fill={buttons}/> </div>);
    
    //... some more code to push more components do divs
    
    return divs;}
export default Core;`
```

Button looks like this:

```
function Button({onClick, className, name}){
    return <button onClick={onClick} className={className} name={name}>{name}</button> 
}
```

and Load like this:

```
export function Load({setRunning, getRunning, setButtonNames, getButtonNames, setProgramCounter, setLines, getBigText}){
    let newButtonName;
    if (!getRunning()){ // Functions errors out with getRunning() undefined 
        herenewButtonName = "Reload";
    }
    else{ //while running if user wants to reload
        newButtonName = "LOAD";
    }

    let lines = getBigText().split(/\n/);
    setLines(lines);
    setProgramCounter(0);
    setRunning(!getRunning());
    
    const newButtonNames = getButtonNames().map((value, index) =>{
        if (index === 0){
            return (newButtonName);
        }
        return value;
    })
    
    setButtonNames(newButtonNames);
}
```

So essentially in my head the flow should be: state methods initialised -> button components created -> wait for click of a button -> update state variablesBut clearly, something goes wrong along the way.

**I've tried** using inspection mode debugging, which revealed that in fact all of the parameters to Load are undefined when they are evaluated.

Note, that everything works as intended if I change the code up like this, eg. just put the whole function within the React component;

```
//... everything same as before
function getQuickbarContents(){
        let functions = [
            () =>{
                let newButtonName;
                if (!getRunning()){ //User clicks to start running
                    newButtonName = "Reload";
                }
                else{
                    newButtonName = "LOAD";
                }
            
                let lines = getBigText().split(/\n/);
                setLines(lines);
                setProgramCounter(0);
                setRunning(!getRunning());
            
                const newButtonNames = getButtonNames().map((value, index) =>{
                    if (index === 0){
                        return (newButtonName);
                    }
                    return value;
                })
            
                setButtonNames(newButtonNames)},
            () => console.log("code running..."),
            () => console.log("stepping to next line..."),
            () => console.log("running to location..."),
            () => Step(setRegisters, registers, setProgramCounter, programCounter, lines[programCounter]),
            () => console.log("pausing..."),
            () => console.log("halting..."),
            () => console.log("running again..."),
            () => console.log("select widget to add...")
        ]
//...everything same as before
```

so consequently the error is somewhere in the way I pass parameters to Load, or maybe I'm doing something I shouldn't be doing in React. Either way I have no clue, any ideas?

Comment: I haven't read all the code, but the main problem I see is that you pass `Load` a lot of different arguments when you call it, yet it's defined as taking a single argument which is an object with those properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in the way parameters were defined in Load, as @robin_zigmond pointed out. Fixed now.